# Array validation using AJAX: show error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, django

Trying to validate arrays via FormRequest validation.
I can access the error message for the field 'name' as `data.responseJSON.error.name[0]` and show it to the user.

```
error: function(data, xhr, errmsg, err){
      console.log("data")
      console.log(data.responseJSON)
      $(".form-alert").fadeIn();
      $(".form-error").text(data.responseJSON.error.name[0]);
```

This works fine. With the same way i access error messages for other fields, however i cannot modify script to handle all errors, i can make it work only with one field as shown above.

How can i modify script to catch errors for example for 'field1', 'field2'.

Thank you

[image: Output data.responseJSON]

contact.html

```
        <!--<h3>Start a project?</h3>-->

          <form class="form" id="contact" method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div id="alert-box"></div>

            <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable form-alert' role="alert" style='display:none'>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <span class='form-error'></span>
            </div>
            {% if form.non_field_errors %}
              <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>{{ form.non_field_errors }}
              </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% for field in form %}
              {% if field.errors %}
                <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>{{ field_errors }}
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}


            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.phone|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.subject|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.website|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.deadline|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.competitors|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.budget_range|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="entry">
                  {{ form.message|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="image-zoom" data-dsn="parallax">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn" style="color: #75DAB4">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Error message shown in user:

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
error: function(data, xhr, errmsg, err){
            $(".form-alert").fadeIn();
            //loop through error
            $.each(data.responseJSON.error, function(i, val) {
            //loop through inner array for each keys
              $.each(val, function(i, val1) {
                console.log(val1)

                error += "<h6>" + val1 + "</h6>" //apppend message in some variable
              })
            })

            $(".form-error").html(error) //add to form-error
```

Comment: You can iterate over all error messages with [the jquery each method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and append the messages to your .form-error element

Comment: @Swati I added error shown in user. Problem is i cannot modify javascript to handle both errors i.e. phone and name in order to show appropriate message.

Comment: Hi Swati, thanks a lot for help but i'm struggling make it work, i modified the script as shown above, check UPDATE. I've run script but message is not displayed. Please show me how to append message in a variable?

Comment: add `var error = "";` line before for-loop .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.each` loop to iterate through your *JSON Object* and then append each error inside some variable using `+=` and lastly add this to your `form-error` span.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = {
  "responseJSON": {
    "error": {
      "phone": ["plese somethings.."],
      "name": ["please filled....","soemhting.."]
    }
  }
}

$(".form-alert").fadeIn();
var error = "";
//loop through error
$.each(data.responseJSON.error, function(i, val) {
//loop through inner array for each keys
  $.each(val, function(i, val1) {
    console.log(val1)
    error += "<h6>" + val1 + "</h6>" //apppend message in some variable
  })
})

$(".form-error").html(error) //add to form-error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable form-alert' role="alert" style='display:none'>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <span class='form-error'></span>
</div>
```